# My Facebook page has been redirected to another account

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook page at the following URL: https://www.facebook.com/111trio

Unfortunately since today, when someone try to access my facebook page from the URL, it is automatically redirected to the following profil: https://www.facebook.com/evelyn.lilly.9

Curiously, my facebook page is still accessible from a smartphone.

Any idea how it is possible? How can I recover my page?

Comment: Did you take a look at this [fb thread](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10153682096109043)?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub This is not exactly the same problem: This is about claiming a page URL that is already reserved by another page. Here the problem is that the page was working with more than 1000 likes and it is like if the URL would have been stolen...

Comment: See the second answer : `my page name is @123hanadulset, but it directs to a certain @morgan.grice.3` it seems this user encounter the same issue, don't you think?

Comment: Fun fact: [even the search is broken](https://www.facebook.com/search/str/111trio/keywords_search). Your page is correctly displayed... At least it's not lost.

Comment: `https://www.facebook.com/111trio/` is accessible.

Comment: Yes I just noticed that!

Comment: The fact that another guy had the same problem one hour ago means there is probably a big bug going on...

Comment: This question is off-topic here. Try [webapps.SE]

Comment: Ok I posted it here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114849/my-facebook-page-has-been-redirected-to-another-account?noredirect=1#comment101658_114849